# Whats is the theme from Attack on titan when Erwin talks with the judge?

Tags: music, attack-on-titan

Do you guys know the name of the theme that plays in the background of the court scene when Erwin talks with the judge?

Answer (score 1):

That's from the track called 'Female Titan Extermination' or 'Megata Kyojin Kuchiku'
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Vs2beUh3k8&list=PLpI7ls08WIzjkLd13vWnKSbIhcpPiybOT&index=11